# Deploy custom InfoPath form with SharePoint list in VS2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, wsp

when I make a list in SharePoint 2010, I have the option to edit the forms for this list using InfoPath (by enabling a feature on the site collection and one on the site). When I save this form, it is saved as the default edit form for the list.

Now I am deploying my list from Visual Studio, as a WSP file. I would like to supply an InfoPath form with this list so that when the feature is activated, the list is created with the custom form attached. I can't seem to be able to find a way to add an InfoPath form to a list in this way though? I have tried creating a module and adding the form in there, but the only thing I can get it to do is to add the form *into* the list, not associate it with the list as an edit form.

I've found [this blog post](http://blog.ksenthil.net/archive/2009/07/25/deployment-of-infopath-form-e28093-the-right-way.aspx), which explains something similar but I'm not sure how it applies to my situation.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow, I have the exact same requirement, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The following tutorial will help you:
http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2010/11/30/deploying-infopath-form-sharepoint/

Important steps along the way:

- Deploy as module
- Use `RegisterForms` in the feature manifest

And here is a link on how to attach your template to your list: http://spforsquirrels.blogspot.com/2008/03/assigning-infopath-form-template-to.html

Take note that you cannot have custom Infopath New/Edit forms for the list as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointinfopath/thread/8d31489c-5c31-4f3f-9ae3-5e59ccb4228a), you can only create a forms library and attach your custom forms template to that library.